# Generate a unique guid in each non Ajax request on Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

All my views have a _ViewStart like that:

```
@{
   if (!Request.IsAjaxRequest())
   {
      Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
   }
}
```

I need generate a unique Guid each non Ajax request and I need access that Guid on all my Actions.

It will be used to add/access Session variables to avoid cross tabs concurrency.

How can I do that?

Comment: I think so, with basic forms Authentication

Comment: @Paul: Then, no, you aren't using OWIN. Forms auth is incompatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to pass this around, and it's going to be *very* fragile. Basically, every form will have to have a hidden input where you can stuff this value, and every link will have to have this value appended as a query string. If you forget to do that even once, then the value will be irreparably lost.

**Forms**

```
@Html.Hidden("guid", Request["guid"])
```

**Links**

```
@Html.ActionLink("SomeAction", new { guid = Request["guid"] })
```

Then, you'll need something for your actions to set this value if it doesn't exist. Most likely you'll want to use a global action filter:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)] 
public class AddGuidAttribute : FilterAttribute, IActionFilter 
{ 
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) 
    {
        var request = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request;
        if (request["guid"] == null)
        {
            var builder = new UriBuilder(request.RawUrl);
            var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);
            query["guid"] = Guid.NewGuid();
            builder.Query = query.ToString();
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(builder.ToString());
        }
    } 
}
```

And then in `FilterConfig.cs`:

```
filters.Add(new AddGuidAttribute());
```